# Where can I find the list of supported attributes for ansible registered variables?

Tags: ansible

On Ansible you can use `register: some_var` in order to save information about executed task but it seems that somehow I am not able to find the list of attributes documented anywhere.

I know about some of them, but I do want a full list as I is really annoying not to have documentation.

- `changed` – set to boolean true if something happened (useful to tell when a task has done something on a remote machine).
- `stderr` – contains stringy output from stderr
- `stdout` – contains stringy output from stdout
- `stdout_lines` – contains a list of lines (i.e. stdout split on \n).

Example, how do I know if the previous task failed?

Answer (score 3):

There is no comprehensive list as each module returns its own list of variables.

There are [common return values](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/common_return_values.html), which describe what a module (should) return as a minimum.

Some modules such as shell, are kind enough to list out the [return values](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html#return-values) they provide in the docs.

I agree it would be quite nice to have a comprehensive cheatsheet listing the modules and return values. As it is, we're stuck with trolling through the python code for each module.

As an [example](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/06e61cf1db53907fd2aa940c96fce9c10e2c2a51/commands/command.py#L234-L244), in the case of `shell` (which uses `command` under the covers), the return values are:

```
module.exit_json(
    cmd      = args,
    stdout   = out.rstrip("\r\n"),
    stderr   = err.rstrip("\r\n"),
    rc       = rc,
    start    = str(startd),
    end      = str(endd),
    delta    = str(delta),
    changed  = True,
    warnings = warnings
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find an official list of the attribute of a register variable either. But I noticed a fact.

Refer to [the explanation of register variable in chapter Loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop). Do you notice what I noticed?

Do you see the "results" part in the Json output in this page? Each key that is present in the "results" part should be the whole attributes of a register variable.

And actually you can show the list of attributes of a register variable by yourself.

See [the registered variable section in chapter Variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables). There is a statement saying: 
**Use of `-v` when executing playbooks will show possible values for the results.**

Answer (score 0):

Refer below url for register module:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables

Also if a any task fails, it will fail the whole ansible playbook and exit. to ignore that and continue we need to use below step under that task

ignore_errors: True

To debug the playbook we are executing, we should pass "-v" to debug.

Comment: That's my point! The documentation does not contain any information regarding what are the attributes that of the registered variable. I managed to find somewhere that there is a `failed` attributed that becomes `true` when the job fails, but where is this documented? So far it seems that we are forced to use the debug mode in order to discover these attributes, which is clearly inconvenient.